# Animate menu with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have  a menu, which I wnat to animate with jquery: This is the Menu HTML:

```
<ul class="shopp_categories">
<li><a href="">Link1</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li><a href="#">Sublink1</a>
            <ul class="children">
                <li><a href="#">Sublink2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And this my js:

```
$(".shopp_categories li").mouseover(function() {
        jQuery(this).children().show()
});

$(".shopp_categories li").mouseout(function() {
        jQuery(this).children().hide()
});
```

The menu is not animtaed correctly. Where is the error? I'd like to use my own function. i know, there are a lot of Plugins available for that, but I prefer a fewe lines of code and not whole Plugin.

This is the menu css:

```
.shopp_categories{padding:0; margin:0 0 15px 0;overflow:hidden; list-style:none}
.shopp_categories li ul{padding:0; margin:0; list-style:none; display:none}
.shopp_categories li{padding-left:7px;overflow:hidden; position:relative}
```

Comment: You know you don't have to have the class set to children to use jQuery's children() selector?

Comment: @Ben Stephenson: Yep, I know, the classes are set by the cms.

Comment: @Zlatev Please have a look above. I added it.

Comment: @ Laura - may I suggest you not to 'hide' elements in your .css! Hide them with jQuery. Some users may have JS disabled in their browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## $('.shopp_categories li').hover(function(){ $(this).children('.children').show(); },function(){ $(this).children('.children').hide(); });

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".shopp_categories li").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).children().show()
    });

    $(".shopp_categories li").mouseout(function() {
            $(this).children('ul').hide()
});
```

Comment: @Laura if you want something different comment me and I'll try to solve.

Comment: @Laura if it gives you success then you should accept it as answer.

Comment: Hi, would it work with toggle() or slideToggle(), too? I tried it, but the behaviour is very strange.